# Php/mysql search engine

Tags: php, mysql, search-engine

How I do exact match or anywhere match keywords on the table with php/mysql search engine.

For example: i added a url with keywords: UFC 131 online
And 2nd url with keywords: UFC 132 online

and if i enter UFC 132 on the search box how do i make the 2nd url to come up first?

Because if i use this code

```
        //explode out search term
 $search_exploded = explode(" ",$search);

 foreach($search_exploded as $search_each)
 {

     //construct query
$x++;
if ($x==1)
 $construct .= "title LIKE '%$search_each%'";
else
 $construct .= " or title = '$search'";
```

and i search for ufc 132 online it gives me ufc 131 online result first.

Comment: please do not post the same question multiple times. It's only been a few minutes, you **can** edit your question if you want to add extra info.

Comment: okey plz delete the other one

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I make other search box more accurate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6296900/how-do-i-make-other-search-box-more-accurate)

Comment: I cannot do that, but you can.

Answer (score 2):

You could implement something like this:

```
SELECT *, MATCH (title) AGAINST ('searchstring' IN BOOLEAN MODE) + 
CASE 
WHEN title = 'searchstring' THEN 10 
ELSE 0
END AS relevance FROM `wrestlingsucks`
HAVING relevance > 1.0
ORDER BY relevance DESC LIMIT 100
```

This is a very basic example, all it will do is add 10 to a sudo relevance column if its an exact match. You could however get as complicated as you want with full text and natural matching.

Comment: Can you tell me where to put the code ? The code i'm using is at http://tinypaste.com/26879

Comment: like i want to do exact keyword match everywhere on the title field for example i added a url with title: Love The Way You Lie ft. Rihanna and i type in love the way you lie i want that url to show up

Comment: This would be the SQL you would use instead of exploding the terms.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL has superior search capabilities for full text search than handcrafting your searches. Take a look at [fulltext-search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-search.html)

Comment: Are you even prepared to try something?

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-search.html#function_match) MATCH (col1,col2,...) AGAINST (expr [search_modifier])

Comment: ? wtf jk seriously idk what that mean

Answer (score 0):

Use Levenshtein algorithm in MySQL.

> Levenshtein matching is a metric for
>   measuring the amount of difference
>   between two sequence, here it is
>   strings. By default MySQL does not
>   have this function, but you can write
>   and add one.

Please take a look at the code here and add that code as a system function in MySQL, please see the example below on how to get the similarity of two strings.

Please see: https://github.com/rakesh-sankar/Tools/blob/master/MySQL/Levenshtein.txt

> Example: SELECT column1,
>   LEVENSHTEIN(column1, 'matchme') AS
>   perfectmatch FROM sometable ORDER BY
>   perfectmatch DESC